# Remove url from source with greasemonkey

Tags: html, greasemonkey

what i want to do is remove url from this

```
<h1 itemprop="name" id="book"><a href="http://www.example.com/book/=/book_num/xxxxxxxxx.html" 
itemprop="url">name of book</a></h1>
```

which will give this

```
<h1 itemprop="name" id="name2">name of book</h1>
```

note that xxxxxxxxx in url differs in every link

Comment: Why do you want to remove the URL?  It isn't visible anyway.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Its in a different language that i can't read,so i need to copy to be able to translate

Comment: What is in a different language?

Comment: The name of the book are in different languages sometime chinese russian korean etc

Answer (score 0):

```
/*--- Use the jQuery contains selector to find content to remove.
    Beware that not all whitespace is as it appears.
*/
var badDivs = $("div div:contains('Annoying text, CASE SENSITIVE')");

badDivs.remove ();
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research got it

```
$("#book a").removeAttr("href");
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11102772)

Comment: @G4M1TG: Huh? How is this should be a comment?